# Reflect.Decorate is not a function

Tags: typescript, decorator, node-modules, inversifyjs

A program I am getting to know the codebase of uses a DecorateAndBind function. While running tests, I got the error message `TypeError: Reflect.decorate is not a function`. Since this didn't seem to come from anything the team here has written themselves, I investigated.

At some point the program calls upon a decorate function in the Inversify module. To be precise it's in `node_modules/inversify/dts/annotation/decorator_utils.d.ts`. In the corresponding `.js` file this refers to Reflect.decorate. I can trace the definition of Reflect to a different module, `node_modules/typescript/lib/lib.es2015.reflect.d.ts`. In this file, Reflect.decorate is not declared.

What can I do to fix this error? I think I shouldn't edit node_modules files myself. Is the initial call to the decorate function in Inversify wrong?

Comment: Related? https://github.com/rbuckton/reflect-metadata

Comment: I don't think so. I found some questions about reflect-metadata when I did my search. I've tried running `npm install reflect-metadata`, this changed nothing for me sadly.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned installing reflect-metadata, but did you also import it? `import "reflect-metadata";`

Comment: I did now, and it just keeps on giving the error. Should I do `import 'reflect-metadata'` in my own test (where Reflect.x is not called) or should I add it to the Inversify node module?

Comment: Found this answer having the same issue - error occuring when using the `@Type` decorator of `class-transformer` : I was importing `"reflect-metadata"` but below some other imports. Moving the line on top of the file solved it.